# Can you use Arcane Bond to cast a spell with a long casting time?

Tags: class-feature, wizard, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

The Drain Bonded Item action says:

> During your turn, you gain the ability to cast one spell you prepared
>   today and already cast (Core 205)

**Does this mean that you cannot use this to cast any spell that you cannot finish in a turn?** Or is it enough to start casting the spell in that turn? Or can you use this action on the turn you finish the spell?

Comment: Do you have an example of a spell that can't be cast in one turn?

Comment: @indigochild There are quite a few. Temporary tool has a casting time of 1 minute, private sanctum needs 10 minutes. Create food takes an hour.

Answer (score 2):

### The ability allows you to cast one spell immediately

The text of the Action to [Drain your Bonded Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=13) is

> During your turn,

is a finite amount of time defined by 6 seconds in Encounter Mode.

> you gain the ability to cast one spell you prepared today and already cast.

is the benefit you gain, which ends after your turn. However, once you've begun casting the spell, you are already casting the spell and I doubt most GM's would say you have to stop casting it. This is further supported by the Action's Requirement

> You haven't acted yet on your turn

---

Incidentally, you are (probably) allowed to use the ability in [Exploration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=521) Mode. It essentially sets you into soft Encounter Mode.

> Actions and Reactions: Though exploration isn’t broken into rounds, exploration activities assume the PCs are spending part of their time using actions, such as Seeking or Interacting. **If they have specific actions they want to use, they should ask; you can decide whether the actions apply and whether to switch to encounter mode for greater detail.** PCs can use any relevant reactions that come up during exploration mode.